# How to use Chinese font Song typeface?

Tags: xetex, xecjk, chinese

I found how to change font to times with:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

But what about Chinese fonts, the instructions I have say I should use `Song typeface`.

I fount this https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese pretty informative, and switched from pdflatex to xelatex already. Also did:

```
% \usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
```

Although I'm still unsure about how to set font to Song typeface. Any suggestion?

Also found these:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces)

Comment: can you try with `\usepackage{xeCJK}`:  `\setCJKmainfont{Song typeface}`?

Comment: maybe there is something related around page 9 of http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf (I cannot read anything, but maybe it helps you)

Comment: page 80 of http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/xetexmain.pdf has an example how to use a font called `song`. Is the font you want to use called `song` or `song typeface`? In the first case I'd like to change my first comment to `\setCJKmainfont{song}`

Comment: You need to have a Song font installed, and then indicate you want to use that font. See for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#xeCJK_Package.

Comment: @jackfrost I'm not sure, it says `Song typeface` for body and for some other parts `Times New Roman` (not Times New Roman typeface). So there is room to think is song typeface.

Comment: @KcFnMi It would be more relevant to know how the font is called in your computer, to get the right name. For example if you use it in Word, how is it called?

Comment: In Word I found `SimSun` and I tried `\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}` and font changes. So I'm guessing it's done, I'm using the song typeface now.

Comment: Still curious about diff between `\setCJKmainfont` and `\setCJKfamilyfont`.